# Shortening down printing single values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have just made this short code for python. It is a timetable for school. I do not use dictionaries that often, because this is the part that i always get confused about.

What I want in the code is the `print(monday["Period 1"])`, which **I repeat 5 times**, to be cleaned up, so it will only require one line of code.

I was thinking maybe I should use a for loop. But since I do not really go towards for loops, I have no idea how to properly use them. Except for once or twice.

Here is my code that I've done **so far**.

```
monday = {"P1" : "1 - English",
      "P2" : "2 - Maths",
      "P3" : "3 - PE",
      "P4" : "4 - Computing",
      "P5" : "5 - Computing"}

choice_day = input("What day would you like to know what you have? ")
choice_period = input("What period? Or just type NO if you want to know the full day: ")

if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
    print(monday["P1"])
    print(monday["P2"])
    print(monday["P3"])
    print(monday["P4"])
    print(monday["P5"])
```

Comment: maybe dictionaries are not that great of a choice here in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of all the values in your dictionary exists as `monday.values()`

```
if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
    for v in monday.values():
        print v
```

or you can put each value from the list into one string joined by newlines:

```
if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
    print '\n'.join(monday.values())
```

If they should be in order, use `sorted`:

```
if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
    print '\n'.join(sorted(monday.values()))
```

Comment: As I could understand that `sorted(monday)` == `sorted(monday.keys())` but `sorted(monday)` is better that `sorted(monday.keys())`  as it need one function call. But to solve further we need `join()`. So which one will be good. `'\n'.join(sorted(monday.values()))` or `'\n'.join(monday[k] for k in order)`  I will prefer your one as first is smaller one. IS there any other reason of preference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to print the values according to the alphabetically sorted keys as in your example, you can use something like the following:

```
if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
    print '\n'.join(monday[k] for k in sorted(monday))
```

If in your actual code the keys should be ordered in a different way than an alphabetical sort and you know what this ordering is in advance, you can do something like the following:

```
order = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"]
if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
    print '\n'.join(monday[k] for k in order)
```

Comment: I am also learner in Python, I want to know `sorted(monday)` ? is it sort by `keys`? and which one better your or `sorted(monday.values()` **?**

Comment: @Grijesh, `sorted` will cast the dict into a list.  If you cast a dict into a list, you just get the keys: `list(monday)` gives `['P2', 'P3', 'P1', 'P4', 'P5']`, the equivalent to `monday.keys()`.

Comment: It isn't really casting, `sorted()` accepts an iterable and returns a sorted list.  When iterating over a dict you get the keys, so `sorted(monday)` is the same as `sorted(monday.keys())`.

Comment: @askewchan  @F.J Ok now I understand,  `sorted(monday)` == `sorted(monday.keys())` but `sorted(monday)` is better as it need one function call --hence fast.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you want to see the courses *in order*. `dict` values are inherently without order. So using a `list` might be more appropriate than using a `dict` here.

```
monday = ["1 - English",
          "2 - Maths",
          "3 - PE",
          "4 - Computing",
          "5 - Computing"]

if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
    for course in monday:
        print(course)
```

By not using a dict you avoid having to sort, or use a list declaring that period 1 comes before period 2, etc. (e.g. `order = ['P1', 'P2', ...]`). The list makes the order built-in.

If for some reason you needed to access, say, the 3rd course on Monday, since Python uses 0-based indexing, you'd write `monday[2]`.

---

You may, however, want to use a dict to represent the entire schedule:

```
schedule = {'monday': ["1 - English",
                       "2 - Maths",
                       "3 - PE",
                       "4 - Computing",
                       "5 - Computing"]
            'tuesday': [...]}
```

You would use a `dict` here since the user may enter *any* day of the week.
If you were always accessing the schedule in order, then you'd want to use an ordered data structure like a list or tuple.

Now you could handle any value for `choice_day` like this:

```
if choice_period == "NO":
    for course in schedule[choice_day]:
        print(course)
```

(Be sure to think about how you want to handle the case when the user enters a `choice_day` that does not exist... One possibility is to vet the choice when it is entered. Another alternative is to use a `try..except` here. A third -- my preference -- is to use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).)

Anyway, using a dict for `schedule` allows you to avoid mind-numbing code like:

```
if choice_day == 'monday':
    ...
elif choice_day == 'tuesday':
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

dict have `values()` method which returns a list of all the values available in a given dictionary.
You can simply iterate over that list, Try this code:

```
if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
 for v in monday.values():
   print v
```

Suppose you just wanted to print keys then use `keys()` method instead of `values()`

```
if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
 for k in monday.keys():
   print k
```

And if you wants to print both keys, values then use `items()`:

```
if choice_day == "monday" and choice_period == "NO":
 for k, v in monday.items():
   print k, v
```

Comment: Thanks! kind of understand that now! :)

Comment: @user2816683 Read [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_values.htm) and read other answer includes other techniques